# Node js - Handle multiple post request with body as file

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

i have built a node js server which receives video file in request which is stored in public folder with the use of multer and then using ffmpeg i am trimming that video, creating poster and compressing the video and then delete main video. Afterwards trimmed video, poster and compressed video are uploaded to s3. There no error in this procedure when the request no is 10-15 but when request amount get bigger the problem comes with ffmpeg. It kill the process. so can anyone guide me.

server configuration : ubuntu server 18, cpu : 2 cores, memory : 2gb, storage: 60gb

thanks in advance.

Comment: what error it throws ?

Comment: Error: ffmpeg was killed with signal SIGKILL
0|app      |     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/uploadfilebackenddemo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:180:22)
0|app      |     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
0|app      |     at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
0|app      |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)